# How do I reset my radio button values when "clear form" is clicked?

Tags: javascript

When I hit "clear form" the Total updates to 0.00 but the each radio button value is not reset to 0.00 within the form. Everything looks like it cleared but the added values are still with in the form. Is there a way to reset all radio button values to 0.00 when I click clear form? Right now they only clear when I refresh the page.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
  var prices = new Object();
    function updateTotal () {
        var total = 0.00;
        for (var price in prices) {
            total += parseInt(prices[price]);
        }
        document.getElementById("total").value = total;   // Add the id "total" to the input field
    }

function doClear()
        {
            document.CustomerForm.customer.value = "";
            document.CustomerForm.address.value = "";
            document.CustomerForm.city.value = "";
            document.CustomerForm.state.options.selectedIndex = "PA";
            document.CustomerForm.zip.value = "";
            document.CustomerForm.phone.value = "";
            document.CustomerForm.email.value = "";
            document.CustomerForm.total.value = 0.00;



            document.OrderForm.tower[0].checked = false;
            document.OrderForm.tower[1].checked = false;
            document.OrderForm.tower[2].checked = false;

            document.OrderForm.monitor[0].checked = false;
            document.OrderForm.monitor[1].checked = false;
            document.OrderForm.monitor[2].checked = false;

            document.OrderForm.printer[0].checked = false;
            document.OrderForm.printer[1].checked = false;
            document.OrderForm.printer[2].checked = false;

            return;
        }
</script>



<body onLoad = "startup()" >  
<h1 align="center">Computer System Order Form</h1>
<!- TODO: implement the order form here--> 
<table border="black" cellpadding="15px" align="center">        
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table cellpadding="15px">
            <form name="OrderForm">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                       <h4>Computer Case Style:</h4>
                        <p>
                        <input type="radio" name="tower" value="500.00" onChange="javascript:prices['tower'] = this.value; updateTotal();" onClick="changeBackground1(this.value);" id="case1" /><label for="case1">Desktop Case ($500.00)</label></br>
                        <input type="radio" name="tower" value="600.00" onChange="javascript:prices['tower'] = this.value; updateTotal();" onClick="changeBackground1(this.value);" id="case2" /><label for="case2">Mini-Tower Case ($600.00)</label></br>
                        <input type="radio" name="tower" value="700.00" onChange="javascript:prices['tower'] = this.value; updateTotal();" onClick="changeBackground1(this.value);" id="case3" /><label for="case3">Full-Tower Case ($700.00)</label></br>
                        </p>
                    </td>

                    <td><img name="casepic" src="case500.jpg" width="125" height="125" id="casepicture"></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <h4>Computer Monitor:</h4>
                        <p>
                        <input type="radio" name="monitor" value="250.00" onChange="javascript:prices['monitor'] = this.value; updateTotal();" onClick="changeBackground2(this.value);" id="monitor1" /><label for="monitor1">17" LCD Flat Screen ($250.00)</label></br>
                        <input type="radio" name="monitor" value="300.00" onChange="javascript:prices['monitor'] = this.value; updateTotal();" onClick="changeBackground2(this.value);" id="monitor2" /><label for="monitor2">19" LCD Flat Screen ($300.00)</label></br>
                        <input type="radio" name="monitor" value="350.00" onChange="javascript:prices['monitor'] = this.value; updateTotal();" onClick="changeBackground2(this.value);" id="monitor3" /><label for="monitor3">21" LCD Flat Screen ($350.00)</label></br>
                        </p>
                    </td>

                    <td><img name="monitorpic" src="monitor250.jpg" width="125" height="125" id="monitorpicture"></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <h4>Computer Printer:</h4>
                        <p>
                        <input type="radio" name="printer" value="100.00" onChange="javascript:prices['printer'] = this.value; updateTotal();" onClick="changeBackground3(this.value);" id="printer1" /><label for="printer1">Inkjet Printer ($100.00)</label></br>
                        <input type="radio" name="printer" value="250.00" onChange="javascript:prices['printer'] = this.value; updateTotal();" onClick="changeBackground3(this.value);" id="printer2" /><label for="printer2">Laser Printer ($250.00)</label></br>
                        <input type="radio" name="printer" value="350.00" onChange="javascript:prices['printer'] = this.value; updateTotal();" onClick="changeBackground3(this.value);" id="printer3" /><label for="printer3">Color Laser Printer ($350.00)</label></br>
                        </p>
                    </td>

                    <td><img name="printpic" src="printer100.jpg" width="125" height="125" id="printerpicture"/></td>
                </tr>
            </form>
            </table>            

        </td>
        <td>


            <table padding="10px">
                <tr>
                <form name="CustomerForm">
                    <td>Total System Price:</td>
                    <td>$<input type="text" name="total" readonly value="0.00" size="10" id="total"></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>Full Name:</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="customer" /></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>Street Address:</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="address" /></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>City:</td> <br>
                    <td><input type="text" name="city" /></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>State:</td>
                    <td>
                        <select name="state"/>
                            <option value="PA">PA</option>
                            <option value="NY">NY</option>
                            <option value="NJ">NJ</option>
                            <option value="DE">DE</option>
                            <option value="FL">FL</option>
                            <option value="ME">ME</option>
                            <option value="CA">CA</option>
                       </select>
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>Zip:</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="zip" /></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>Phone Number:</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="phone" /></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>Email Address:</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="email"></td>
                </tr>
                </form>

                <tr>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td><input type="button" value="Submit Order" onClick="doSubmit()" /></td>
                    <td><input type="button" value="Clear Form" onClick="doClear()" /></td>
                </tr>
            </table>



        </td>       
    </tr>   
</table>
```

Comment: What's the reason for implementing our own logic instead of using a `<input type="reset" />` button?

Comment: There is no radio button with value `0.00`. So what exactly do you mean by *"Is there a way to reset all radio button values to 0.00 when I click clear form?"*? If you are talking about the `prices` variable, then you can just initialize it with a new object: `prices = {}`.

Comment: I'm very new to javascript so bare with me: my values add up and then when I click the "clear form" button the value in the total box says 0 but the values I clicked before still are there. All radio buttons look like they are not checked but when I click the first computer case which has a value of $500 the total box will say a larger value because all of the old value were not reset to 0. They do reset to 0 when I refresh the page though.

Comment: Yep, for the reason I mentioned in my comment and in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Given that the radio elements are correctly unchecked (http://jsfiddle.net/4h84V/), I assume that you are talking about that the values in the `prices` variable are not reset. You can achieve that easily by assigning an empty object to it, inside `clearForm`:

```
function clearForm() {
    // ... other code
    prices = {}; // "reset" `prices` to an empty object
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/4h84V/2/)

---

Further notes:

Instead of using your own reset logic, you might be better off using a reset button:

```
<input type="reset" value="Clear Form" />
```

It will automatically reset the values of all form control elements to their default value.

However, if you want to reset radio buttons programmatically, the best approach is to access their `defaultChecked` property:

> The default state of a radio button or checkbox as originally specified in HTML that created this object.

With this property you can truly reset a radio button.

Example:

```
var radios = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"]');
for (var i  = 0, l = radios.length; i < l; i++) {
    radios[i].checked = radios[i].defaultChecked;
}
```

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work...
<input type="reset" value="Clear Form" />

Comment: @TrayCeeee: Well, I didn't know what your actual problem was. You'd still have to assign a click event handler and reset `prices`.

Comment: Here is an updated version how I would do it: http://jsfiddle.net/4h84V/1/. Note that there were a couple other things that were incorrect in your code: `form` element cannot be children of `table` elements, you have to put the table inside the form. If you want the default reset button affect all input elements, you have to create *one* form. In this solution instead of relying on the `prices` variable, I just iterate over the checked radio buttons when the total is updated.

Comment: You are awesome! Thank you for ending my suffering. THANK YOU! THANK YOU!

Comment: Work here with a small change. An if to find the default item and them mark it again, like this: ``` var radios = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"]');
 for (var i  = 0, l = radios.length; i < l; i++) {
  if(radios[i].value == 'name of default option'){
   radios[i].defaultChecked = 'true'; <<<< Add this
   radios[i].checked = radios[i].defaultChecked;
  }
 }  ```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var myRadioList = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
for (i = 0; i < myRadioList.length; i++) 
{
  if (myRadioList[i].type == "radio")
  {
    myRadioList[i].checked = false; 
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

With jQuery it is as simple as:

```
$('input[name=montior]').attr('checked',false);
```

or in pure Javascript:

```
   var ele = document.getElementsByName("monitor");
   for(var i=0;i<ele.length;i++)
      ele[i].checked = false;
```

Comment: It's not pretty how the OP unchecks the radio buttons, but that's not the problem, so your answer won't help.